# How to pass a parameterized INTERVAL in a slonik/postgres query?

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres, slonik

This query seems to be legal when I run it in Datagrip with a parameter value of `'14 days'`
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.updated_at < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL $1)`

But trying to do something similar in slonik as below does not:

```
const interval='14 days'
// ...
const {rows} = await pool.query<any>(sql`
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.updated_at < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL ${interval}))
`)
```

Seems to yield the same query: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated_at < CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL $1)"` but the pool's `query` method throws a `syntax error near "$1"` error when I try to execute it.

I've tried a couple of variations including escaping the input `const interval="'14 days'"` and adding parens for the INTERVAL function `(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(${interval}))` with the same error results.

Is it not possible to parameterize a slonik query this way or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 4):

You can subtract an integer representing the number of days from `CURRENT_DATE` because that is a `date` value not a `timestamp`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated_at < CURRENT_DATE - $1
```

Then pass `$1` as an integer

Another option is to multiply an `interval` of a specific length with the parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated_at < CURRENT_DATE - (interval '1 day' * $1)
```

or use the `make_interval()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated_at < CURRENT_DATE - make_interval(days => $1)
```

Comment: I'm aware of most of those alternatives already, what I really want to do is parameterize the whole expression, like I seem to be able to do when slonik isn't involved. That's not possible?

Comment: /u/a_horse_with_no_name answer is correct, but Slonik now has `sql.interval` helper. https://github.com/gajus/slonik#user-content-slonik-query-building-sql-interval